# iPhone 5 USB Audio

Tags: audio, usb, iphone, lightning

I've been reading up on the Lightning cable, and there's been some debate over whether it transmits analog audio. I'm not sure how exactly the 30-pin connector works, or how the Lightning cable works (that electrical engineer stuff is over my head).

I would like to know however if I am able to play audio into my car stereo from the iPhone 5. My car stereo, has a usb port that can connect to my iPhone via the 30-pin port. Does the iPhone 5 (with Lightning cable) have compatibility with these types of devices?

Edit: For those interested, I'm not going to buy a 5; I'm due for an upgrade now, and I'll be getting the new iPhone whenever it's announced. I'd just like to know what the compatibility with my current setup will look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works through the regular 30-pin to USB cable, it should work with the Lightning to USB cable as well.

This type of connection is through an all digital interface and I am not aware of any changes to it, when the lightning connector was introduced.

It's a different story, when you have a Y-Cable for your car. This would have a dock-connector on one side and a USB and Headphone-jack on the other.

In this case you will need a Lightning to 30-pin adapter. This would be an analog connection and the adapter would do the conversion from a digital into an analog signal.